# How to make TeamCity artifacts containing build number?

Tags: java, gradle, build, teamcity

I want an artifact name for e.g. `game-1.0.%BuilNumber%.jar` where `BuildNumber` is number of teamcity build.

I am using gradle to build artifacts. Is it with that tool possible or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teamcity exposes [build parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Gradle) via a Gradle project property called `teamcity`. This would allow you to do something like:

```
jar {
    version += '.' + teamcity['build.number']
}
```

Comment: I'm really gratefull. I needed to add if(hasProperty("teamcity")) to run it also locally